# Make a fragment container full screen programatically

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to create a single activity app using bottom navigation but want my login fragments to be full screen. Is there a way to do this in the code?

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            if (destination.id == R.id.loginLandingFragment) {
                //MAKE FULLSCREEN HERE
            }
        }


        bottomNavigationView?.setupWithNavController(navController)

        navController.navigate(R.id.loginLandingFragment)

    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
    >


    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am essentially trying to use this one activity for my entire app and I want to be able to present fragments that will cover the bottom nav menu.

Not sure if this is possible or if I have to use a second activity. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide navigation bar on the fragments you don't want it to be shown like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            if (destination.id == R.id.loginLandingFragment) {
                bottomNavigationView.isVisible = false
            } else {
                bottomNavigationView.isVisible = true
            }
        }


        bottomNavigationView?.setupWithNavController(navController)

        navController.navigate(R.id.loginLandingFragment)

    }
}
```

Also you'll need to import `androidx.core.view.isVisible` from androidX library.

Comment: I added the XML see if that better explains my question?

Comment: Oh, now I see what you want to achieve. I updated my answer, please review it